# VS Code Typescript IntelliSense does not suggest namespace from global.d.ts

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, .d.ts

If I declare the namespace globally for an application, I can use it (it works without compilation errors), but I won't have suggestion/autocompletion for the namespace specifically. However types from this namespace do appear in the intellisense suggestions.

In other words, while I type the namespace (for example `libTypes`) there are no suggestions for it, but after I finish typing the namespace and add a dot after it (`libTypes.`) intellisense starts suggesting me all the available types in this namespace.

###### Example of global.d.ts

```js
import * as _libTypes from 'library/types';
declare global {
    const libTypes: typeof _libTypes;
}

export as namespace libTypes;
export = _libTypes;
```

###### tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the tsconfig.json like this

##### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "types"
  ]
}
```